# Javascript created dropdown expands on a single line

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have created at work a dynamically created dropdown. My HTML code is simply

```
<SELECT id="competitors">
  <OPTION value="0">All values</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

I have created a js function that on focus executes the appropriate queries and appends the html.

```
success: function (data) {
   $(id).append(data.arr);
 )
```

It appends pure HTML as I loop an array

```
$text .= "<OPTION value=\"$id\">$name</OPTION>";
```

and afterwards I encode the string

```
$str['arr'] = $text;
echo json_encode($str);
```

CSS for the dropdown has only width property and this dropdown is among others that all follow the same rules(dynamically created using on focus functions).

The problem is that when I click the dropdown after appending the data, it does not expand. It remains a single line dropbox with "navigation bar"
So when I click it whlie it is getting the data it looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE5Bc.png)
and after the response instead of a full dropdown I get [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLids.png)

Information that might be helpful are that:
1.The request might take long (2-10 seconds) as I have to join multiple tables and to group some hundrends of thousands of lines. 
2.After the response when I got the 1 line dropdown with navigation bar if I reclick it it expands as it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's taking that long to return your results, you could disable the dropdown until your callback is successful?

Comment: What does the `data.arr` contains? On the other hand since you are using jQuery, would you like to use jQuery instead to get the job done?

Comment: @Raptor data.arr contains the json_encode of an array that contains of the $str['arr']. $str['arr'] has only one element that is the HTML of the list. It is something like $str['arr'][0]= <OPTION value="1">nameof1</OPTION><OPTION value="2">nameof2</OPTION><OPTION value="3">nameof3</OPTION> . I will try to use pure jQuery and I will come back with results. Thnx anyway.

Comment: @DevlshOne What do you mean by saying "disable the dropdown". As I said these are my first attempts  with the J world (jQuery, javascript...) so ... Anyway, I 'll google it and return. thnx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

well you can do something like this using javascript

html:

```
<select id="competitors">
    <option value="0"> All values </option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('competitors').options[competitors.options.length]
 = new Option('theName', 'the value');
```

here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f5a81Lv6/